# Set Spring Tools 4 logging level

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite

I have installed Spring Tools 4 in Eclipse, and they started logging a lot of information messages in Error Log view, particularly the `org.springframework.tooling.ls.eclipse.commons` plugin. Is there a way to disable logging information messages for this plugin?

Comment: This might be caused by an outdated Eclipse version or some other plug-ins you have installed. If you are still seeing errors with the current Eclipse version and the current STS4 version without additional plug-ins, make sure it has been reported (this is the reason for having the error log).

Comment: There must be a way to configure the log level of individual bundles, but I can't find that at the moment. Will dig deeper to find a solution for this. In the meantime, you could configure the `Error Log` view via `Filters` to not show information messages (as a quick workaround).